Changes not reflected in my VS Code ASP.NET Web API project when running in debug mode
I seem to be getting a cached version of my ASP.NET Web API project in VS Code when debugging. I have made changes, like adding a new controller or debug statement in an existing one but when I press debug and call the
I see it pulling the right launch settings file:

Using launch settings from '/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Projects/zzzzzzzzzz/yyyyyyyyyy/Properties/launchSettings.json' [Profile 'yyyyyyy']...

I made a simple change like from this:
_logger.LogDebug("TestController.Post method called.");

To this:
_logger.LogDebug("TestController.Post method called for v3.");

to test as there were a bunch of changes not getting picked up, but the log file continues to show:

xxxxx.Controllers.v3.TestController: Debug: TestController.Post
method called.

When I call the API. Other problems seem to indicate an older version is being run for example:

There is an error in processing a post, I've fixed it, but the same line number is showing even after I've changed it and it's on a different line.
I've added new controllers and am getting 404 errors when calling them

